# Java // Redundancy

Tags: java

I have 'sample code' as provided below, I find this very redundant, and would like to ask you to work with me in explaining if there is any less redundant way to deal with the following code.

```
public interface Bars {

    FOO1 FOO1 = (FOO1) get(FOO1.class);
    FOO2 FOO2 = (FOO2) get(FOO2.class);
    FOO3 FOO3 = (FOO3) get(FOO3.class);
    FOO4 FOO4 = (FOO4) get(FOO4.class);

    static Bar get(Class<? extends Bar> clazz) {
        return (Bar) FooBar.GET.getBars().get(clazz);
    }
```

Greatly Appreciate It :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We need to see more to advise if this code can be removed altogether (looks like you want to use a DI framework), but you could make the get method generic to have it return the same type as its parameter:

```
static <T extends Bar> T get(Class<T> clazz);
```

That would get rid of the typecasts on the call-side.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to write it like this:

```
public interface Bars {

    Foo1 FOO1 = get(Foo1.class);
    Foo2 FOO2 = get(Foo2.class);
    Foo3 FOO3 = get(Foo3.class);
    Foo4 FOO4 = get(Foo4.class);

    static <T extends Bar> T get(Class<T> clazz) {
        return clazz.cast(FooBar.GET.getBars().get(clazz));
    }
}
```

The `cast(...)` call may not be necessary, depending on the declared result type of the `get(Class)` method.

After that, I don't think there is a *better* way to initialize 4 distinct variables with different types.

If these were local variables, and if you are using Java 10 or later, you could use the new `var` syntax so that you don't need to mention the types in the declarations.  (The types would be inferred from the initializer expressions.)

However, that doesn't apply in this case because your example shows these variables as fields of an interface.  The `var` syntax can only be used in declarations of local variables.

Answer (score 2):

Change the `get` method to:

```
static <T extends Bar> T get(Class<T> clazz) {
    return clazz.cast(FooBar.GET.getBars().get(clazz));
}
```

You can now call it without repeating the types:

```
var foo1 = get(Foo1.class);
var foo2 = get(Foo2.class);
```

The `var` syntax only works for Java 10+. Before Java 10, you'd need:

```
Foo1 foo1 = get(Foo1.class);
Foo2 foo2 = get(Foo2.class);
```

Note that I've changed letters to lowercase above to conform to Java naming conventions.

Comment: I was always taught that it was improper to write interface fields as lowercase because it was redundant to define an interface field with a final modifier; regardless, thank you for the response

Comment: @Christian Sorry, I assumed that writing the fields as part of the interface was for brevity of the example, and that they were actually local variables in some method.

Comment: My apologies, I should have been more clear; thanks for the answer; I just wanted to know if I was taught correctly or not..